# clicking button vs ('jqueryObject').click() causes different reults in ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, search, custom-server-controls

I have a search textbox and a button, when clicked using the mouse, the textbox text is used in serverside code to filter results... Behind the scene this is done using Ajax and this works fine.

I would like to create a clientsdie keypress event, so when the user presses enter in the box, the search button is clicked.

When I use a ('#somebutton').click() (or equivalent ('#somebutton').trigger("click")), within the textbox keypress event, the server side code runs but takes the old textbox search value... here's an example of what is going on.

[Using Mouse]

1. Type "Mary" into search box, click search with mouse, results returned for Mary.
2. Type "Bob" into search box, click search with mouse, results returned for Bob.

[Using Keypress event and trigger click method]

1. Type "Mary" into search box, and press enter, results returned for "".
2. Type "Bob" into search box, and press enter, results returned for Mary.

Here is my client side code running within $(document).ready event.

```
    $('.txtSearch').keypress(function(event){

        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if(keycode == '13'){
            $('.btnSearch').click();            
        }

    });
```

Can anyone explain why the click event through JQuery does not take the current search textbox value, but actually clicking the button with the mouse does?

Thanks...

Also... This search box is a custom built server control, therefore the components such as textbox and button are created in code each time in the Control.CreateChildControls method.

My only guesses from here are

1. Clicking the search button somehow fires the server side click event later in the lifecycle than when using the JQuery.click() method... (unlikely to be this) or
2. Something regarding the viewstate data.  Maybe the JQuery method of firing off a click event causes the viewstate data to bind back with the server control after I need it.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the button click event?  I suspect that's where the problem lies.

Comment: You can't call button server side click event through jquery function.

Comment: @Raghubar The button already works fine so that's not relevant.  Also, it's an AJAX call, not a postback event.

Comment: The issue is before the server side code is hit.  When the server side click event runs, prior to any code being run, I can test the textbox.text value each time. When the button is clicked, the textbox text is correct, when I use JQuery to fire the click method, the previous value appears...

Comment: Afaik, the value of a textbox is internally not changed, until the box looses focus. Can you test that using the `onchange` event of the textbox?

Comment: **THATS IT!!!** Ha... I was looking everywhere for this and it was under my nose... I can't believe it... I changed focus out of the text box and it worked... Wutz, you've made my day, **thanks very much! I owe you one!**